# Notification.permission in Xamarin Webview

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, webview, notifications

I am quite new to Xamarin App Development.
I have a web application using FirebaseNotifications. In the webapp I use this javascript code for checking whether notficatons are accepted.

```
 if (Notification.permission !== "granted") {
            Notification.requestPermission();
        }
```

This works pretty well, I can then receive notifications using

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
   //do something
}
```

BUT, when I call the same website in an XamarinForms WebView, I get an exception, that `Notificaton` is null. Therefore I can not grant the the permission and not receive any messages.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Notification spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/permission it is not supported in Android WebView nor iOS WebView which Xamarin.Forms uses behind the scenes. This Notification permission request is for web browsers only.

[image: Notifications suppor matrix]

Hence, this Notification permission, is not necessary to receive notifications in Mobile Applications. For a mobile App to receive notifications you need a different type of setup. You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows

It will involve you having to install GooglePlayServices and FirebaseMessaging from NuGet and configuring those for each of your platforms your App runs on.

If you want to invoke some native code to set up these notifications when you call some specific JavaScript in your WebApp, check out the documentation on creating a Custom Renderer for your WebView here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview#create-the-custom-renderer-on-android